# Laravel 5.5 : htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

The below view throws the following error: `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`. Weirdly enough this code worked fine for a while before this error popped up.

(The error only comes when the following form is posted. There are no errors while the view is being loaded)

```
@extends($template)

@section('content')

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom: 50px;">

    <div class="row">

        <!-- Blog Entries Column -->
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <h1 class="my-4">Report Incident
            </h1>

            <form action="{{ route('add_post') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('title') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Title" value="{{ old('title') }}" required>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {{ $errors->first('title') }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="date">Date of incident</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('date') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="date" name="date" required value="{{ old('date') }}">
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {{ $errors->first('date') }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="type">Incident Type</label>
                    <select class="form-control {{ $errors->has('type') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="type" name="type">
                        @foreach($types as $type => $icon)
                            @if($type == old('type'))
                                <option value="{{ $type }}" selected>{{ $type }}</option>
                            @else
                                <option value="{{ $type }}">{{ $type }}</option>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {{ $errors->first('type') }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="description">Description</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control {{ $errors->has('description') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="description" name="description" rows="5" required>{{ old('description') }}</textarea>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {{ $errors->first('description') }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="images">Upload images (if any)</label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control-file {{ $errors->has('images') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="images" name="images[]" value="{{ old('images') }}" accept=".jpg, .png" multiple>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {{ $errors->first('images') }}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="province">Select Province</label>
                    <select class="form-control {{ $errors->has('province') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="province" name="province">
                        @foreach($provinces as $province)
                            @if($province == old('$province'))
                                <option value="{{ $province }}" selected>{{ $province }}</option>
                            @else
                                <option value="{{ $province }}">{{ $province }}</option>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {{ $errors->first('province') }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pac-input">Please type in a location</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('pac-input') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="pac-input" name="pac-input" placeholder="Location" value="{{ old('pac-input') }}" required>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {{ $errors->first('pac-input') }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Please select an approximate location from the map</label>
                    <div id="map" style="height: 500px; width: 100%;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-block">
                    <label for="lat">Latitude</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lat" id="lat" class="form-control" value="{{ old('lat') }}" readonly>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-block">
                    <label for="lng" style="margin-top: 10px;">Longitude</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lng" id="lng" class="form-control" value="{{ old('lng') }}" readonly>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-6 col-md-4">


                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <br><br><input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-success" value="Submit">
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

</div>


<script>
    var map;
    function initAutocomplete(){
        console.log(document.getElementById('map'));
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: 6.870066, lng: 79.879710},
            zoom: 15
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {
                lat: 16.870066,
                lng: 80.879710
            },
            map: map,
            draggable: true
        });

//            document.getElementById('lat').value = marker.getPosition().lat();
//            document.getElementById('lng').value = marker.getPosition().lng();

        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');

        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);

        google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed',function(){
            var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var i, place;

            for (i=0; place=places[i]; i++) {
                bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
                marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
            }

            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            map.setZoom(15);
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'position_changed', function(){
            var lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
            var lng = marker.getPosition().lng();

            document.getElementById('lat').value = lat;
            document.getElementById('lng').value = lng;
        });
    }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY_WAS_HERE&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer></script>

@endsection
```

I think it has something to do with my declaration of my file uploads input:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label for="images">Upload images (if any)</label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control-file {{ $errors->has('images') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="images" name="images[]" value="{{ old('images') }}" accept=".jpg, .png" multiple>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {{ $errors->first('images') }}
                    </div>
</div>
```

The name I have given the following input is `images[]` since I want multiple images to be uploaded. When I change the name from `images[]` to `images`, the error seems to go away but no images are uploaded/saved (if needed the code to handle the backend image uploading can be posted as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you expect PHP to echo an array? It can't.

Your inputs are using array naming. So on the server side `images` in the request is an array. So the "old" data for `images` is an array, not a single value. You are trying to echo an array  `{{ old('images') }}`.

First you can't set a value on a file input. That would be a security concern.

Second you have potentially multiple files not one, so what value are you trying to set it to? What do you think `old('images')` will be besides an array?

Comment: Oh right, right I get it.. Basically, I set the value to `old('images')` because I want the selected images to be retained in case there is an error in the form. I now realize that's not possible. I'm going to process/save the uploaded files regardless whether or not my form has validation errors (if there are no validation errors with the uploaded files), and it seems to be working now. Thanks a bunch!